# Screenshot view for link as Google instant view or twitter dynamic link view (how to???)

Tags: jquery

Does there is any way to dynamically open a page in the popup when place mouse over the link. Examples are Wordpress page screenshot view, Google instant view, Twitter dynamic user posts views. etc.... (through JQuery)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into [websnapr.com](http://www.websnapr.com/). They provide an API for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in JavaScript alone...the server is doing the rendering work (generating the images) for these pages.  You could do a `<iframe>` with a small zoom, but I'd *really* recommend against this, as it'd be unreliable at best depending on the site's styling.